# ServiceStack .NET standard libraries are missing the PublicKeyToken

Tags: servicestack, .net-standard-2.0, servicestack-text

I have a .NET framework website running on 4.7.2 that references the ServiceStack.Text library and I only have a reference to a .NET Standard project which itself references ServiceStack.Text as well.

When I run the application I get an exception that the ServiceStack.Text cannot be found as it is looking for the ServiceStack.Text assembly with PublicKeyToken null but the ServiceStack.Text .NET framework assembly is actually having a PublicKeyToken assigned, hence the exception.

[image]

[image]

Has anybody else experienced this before?